# Command prompt: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/TestNG : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, testng, prompt

I am trying to run a testing file in command prompt windows 10 system. Getting following  error please help.

I tried running using below command `java -cp "lib/*;bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`
same file works in my own laptop but not in my  office system?

Java and jre versions installed in my office system are as below:

- jdk-12.0.2
- jre6

System variable `JAVA_HOME` is set for `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2`

> Note: I don't have admin access to install/update any software updates. Is there any workaround to get this running?

I know this question has been asked before. But, looks like that is related to Java program eclipse run.

Comment: Hi This got resolved if i set path to my jdk before my xml file.

Comment: If you solved your own problem in about an hour of "not getting anyone's help" then this is very much a case of "a question that just needed some more investigation by you", and should be deleted again.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` has no effect if you use `java` directly.  What actually matters is the `PATH` setting ... which determines the `java` executable that you use .... and the `CLASSPATH` or `-cp` argument.